# font size issue with <p> tag inside button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

button size not changing with font size on button with paragraph

```html
   <button style="font-size: 10px; color: white; font-weight: 500; width: auto; height: auto;" class="sc-fLcnxK dLvstt">
  <p style="font-weight: 500; color: #FFFFFF; display: block; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px;" class="sc-fnGiBr hMZmkR">Button</p>
</button>
```

Comment: You should not be using a paragraph element inside a button element. This is not allowed by HTML standards. A paragraph is a block-level element, whereas a button is an inline element. Generally, you are not allowed to put a block-level element inside an inline element. You also seem to be confusing CSS styles with element attributes. CSS styles should not use an equal sign. Learning to do an external style sheet will help you a lot.

Comment: You should also try pasting your code in a validator to see what it says. There are two validators here that will help: https://validator.w3.org and https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator (try the "direct input" option on each site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are making a mistake that you can not use style properties like this. Instead use the style attribute as below. Also do not use p tag inside button tag cause button tag is inline elem whereas p tag is a block elem.

```html
<button style="font-size:20px; color:black; font-weight:500; width:auto; height:auto;" class="sc-fLcnxK dLvstt">
     Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes, I am using the style attribute with the button but it is not working.  Is it because the P tag is a block element as you said?

Comment: @AbhishekKhune That's probably not the reason it's not working for you. But yes, you should not be using a `p` element inside a `button` element. What is wrong with the code that Snehil gave you?

Comment: Is this not working @AKStacks??

Comment: even if you put  a p tag inside the button it will work. But that is considered a bad practice coz we cant put block elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

This are some samples of buttons. I would suggest you use the sample button number 3 which put on a class and externalized the css. play with it hope this helps you.

```css
.button-3 {

  font-family: inherit; 
  font-size: 16px; color: white; 
  font-weight: 500; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
SAMPLE #1

<button style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; color: white; font-weight: 500; width: auto; height: auto; color: #FFFFFF;" class="sc-fLcnxK dLvstt">Button</button>

<br />
<br />
SAMPLE #2

<button style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 10px; color: white; font-weight: 500; width: auto; height: auto; color: #FFFFFF;" class="sc-fLcnxK dLvstt">Button</button>


<br />
<br />
SAMPLE #3

<button class="button-3">
Button
</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try inline style css. hope this will work.